# How to fix it in BST insertion and let the insertion function work

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

[The code showed in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DahL.png)The InsertBSTNode function is wrong. But I don't know how to fix it. The requirement is that do not change the type of the function.

TreeNode

```
 class TreeNode{   
    public:
    int data;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;

    TreeNode(int x): data(x), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
    };
```

InsertBSTNode

```
void InsertBSTNode(TreeNode* &root, int val){
// Input your code here.
if (root==NULL){
    root->data=val;
    root->left=root->right=NULL;}
else if(val<root->data)
    root->left=InsertBSTNode(root->left,val);//error
else if(val>root->data)
    root->right=InsertBSTNode(root->right,val);//error
return root;//error

};
```

Comment: It's very simple, you've written your function as `void InsertBSTNode(...)` A `void` function has no return value. But in your code you do have a return value because you say `return root;`. Either write a function that doesn't return a value, or replace `void` with the return type of your function. Your choice.

Comment: The problem is how to write a function weithout return when it needs to recurision.

Comment: Recusrive functions don't have to have return types. It's not that you are calling the function recursively that is the problem. If you want a void recusive function then just fix the three errors, delete `root->left=`, `root->right=` and `return root;`

Comment: BTW, this is an obvious error `if (root==NULL){
    root->data=val;
    root->left=root->right=NULL;}` you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your correction, but if I remove all this, the insertion still doesn't work.

Comment: All reasonable feedback from the reviewers.  Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the code I think you are trying to write

```
void InsertBSTNode(TreeNode* &root, int val) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new TreeNode;
        root->data=val;
        root->left=root->right=NULL;
    }
    else if (val<root->data)
        InsertBSTNode(root->left,val);
    else
        InsertBSTNode(root->right,val);
}
```

I've fixed the invalid use of return values, and I've fixed the NULL pointer error by allocating a node at the place where you do the insert.

Comment: I have tried this before, but it seems to be stack overflow when doing the recurision.

Comment: @FutamonoMyo That would indicate your tree is corrupt. If you look at the function it can only infinitely recurse if the tree has a cycle in it. One of the left or right nodes is pointing back up the tree.

Comment: Very appreciate for your help!  Your code works if “new TreeNode” changes to "new TreeNode(val)". Sorry for bothering you so many times!

Comment: @FutamonoMyo Glad to help, I hadn't seen your TreeNode class before. Obviously you can delete `root->data=val;
        root->left=root->right=NULL;` as well now, because all of that is done in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the question. Thanks for @john helping!

```
void InsertBSTNode(TreeNode* &root, int val){
if (root==NULL){
    root = new TreeNode(val);
    root->data=val;
    root->left=root->right=NULL;}
else if(val<root->data)
    InsertBSTNode(root->left,val);
else if(val>root->data)
    InsertBSTNode(root->right,val);
};
```